# SPRING-DATA-JPA Simple Auditing Not Working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am trying to make use of the auditing provided by spring data jpa.Below is my webappconfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.astrika.kernel")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.astrika.kernel.repository")
@EnableJpaAuditing

public class WebAppConfig {

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";


private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_POST_INSERT = "hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_POST_UPDATE = "hibernate.ejb.event.post-update";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_POST_DELETE = "hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_PRE_COLLC_UPDATE = "hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_PRE_COLLC_REMOVE = "hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_PRE_COLLC_RECREATE = "hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate";

@Resource
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setMappingResources("WEB-INF/classes/orm.xml");
     //     entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

//  private Properties hibProperties() {
//      Properties properties = new Properties();
//      properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_POST_INSERT, 

// env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_POST_INSERT));
//      properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_POST_UPDATE, 

// env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_POST_UPDATE));
//      properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_POST_DELETE, 

// env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_POST_DELETE));
//      properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_PRE_COLLC_UPDATE,    

// env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_PRE_COLLC_UPDATE));
//      properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_PRE_COLLC_REMOVE,    

// env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_PRE_COLLC_REMOVE));
//      properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_PRE_COLLC_RECREATE,  

// env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_PRE_COLLC_RECREATE));
//      return properties;
//  }
 @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new  

HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename(env.getRequiredProperty("message.source.basename"));
    source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return source;
}
```

and my orm.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd" 
    version="2.0">

<persistence-unit-metadata>
    <persistence-unit-defaults>
        <entity-listeners>
            <entity-listener class="org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener" />
        </entity-listeners>
    </persistence-unit-defaults>
</persistence-unit-metadata>
```

When ever i run my application in my tomcat server i get the error

```
INFO: HHH000360: Unable to resolve mapping file [WEB-INF/classes/orm.xml]
```

And the audit fields like createdOn,lastModifiedOn never gets a value.They always null.
Please help as why i get the above tomcat error? and is it responsible for null values on audit fields? and am i missing any more configuration?

I forgot to mention i am using annotation based auditing i.e. @CreatedOn and 
@LastModifiedOn

Comment: Is your orm.xml file in META-INF/orm.xml?

Comment: no its under resources which after deployment goes to web-inf/classes/

Comment: Try to put your orm.xml under src/main/resources in META-INF directory and remove setMappingResources from your WebAppConfig. Does it works?

Comment: Ok if i remove setMappingResources, how my application is going to know about the existence orm.xml file.I need the entity listener i have in orm.xml, to configure my application for auditing i.e. for CreatedOn and LastModifiedOn annotations.
Right now properties in my pojo marked with CreatedOn and LastModifiedOn annotations get null values.

Comment: The default position of orm.xml is under src/main/resources in META-INF. Thats why I suggest you to remove the custom location. If you remove setMappingResources, orm.xml is searched in its default position.

Comment: I did what u said and removed setMappingResourses and now my orm.xml is not being scanned at all.I have confirmed this by introducing errors in the xml file.
Plus i didn't get when you said "orm.xml is searched in its default location". If i am not telling my app to read from so n so file how its going to read from that file? No where in the application i have specified to even look for the orm.xml file

Comment: Although I second mserioli's recommendation to move `orm.xml` into its recommended location, his tip to simply not list the mapping file is wrong. If you use `packages` to scan, Spring builds up a default `PersistenceUnitInformation` and hands it to the persistence provider, which then in turn *skips the scanning for mapping files* (as it doesn't see a reasonable persistence unit root URL). That's why you have to list your mapping file manually. See my answer below for details on that one.

Comment: Thnx mserioli for trying to help

Comment: You are welcome! And thanks to @OliverGierke that teach me something new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA mapping files have to be referenced from the classpath by definition. Thus it's best to keep them in `src/main/resources/META-INF`, for example. They can then be referred to through:

```
emfb.setMappingResources("META-INF/orm.xml");
```

So I recommend moving the file but with your current setup you should be able to get it working if you configure the mapping resource to simply be `orm.xml` (i.e. strip off the `WEB-INF/classes` prefix.

Comment: Thanx a lot dude the striping off "WEB-INF/classes" worked like a charm. Now i am getting data too long for createdOn column dont know why as i have used annotaions for CreatedOn and LastModifiedOn. If you can please let me know what to do. 
I am using Joda datetime for the columns and hibernate to create tables and columns

Comment: By default, Hibernate maps unknown types as a blob, which probably is not what you want. Have a look at http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html for a library with Hibernate specific type converters for JodaTime. Alternatively you can use standard `Date` objects internally and just expose JodaTime types on the getters and manually do the conversion.